# conversion of dictionary to json to be sent to requests.post

Tags: python, pandas, json

I have a data frame like this.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'sub1':[10,20,30,40],'sub2':[5,10,15,20],'sub3':[1,2,3,4]})
```

and a dictionary like this.

```
stud={}
stud['name']="abc"
stud['id'] ="AB10"
stud['address']="some_address"
```

I convert that data frame to dictionary and combine with the stud dictionary.I wrote the following code.Then this stud dictionary should be made in a json format and sent as a web service.

```
stud={}
stud['name']="abc"
stud['id'] ="AB10"
stud['address']="some_address"
for i in range(0,len(df)):
   data_sample={}
   data_sample_row=df.iloc[i]
   a=data_sample_row.to_dict()
   stud['data_sample']=a
   str_details=str(stud)
```

I would like to get the result as shown below.

```
"{'name':'abc','id':'AB10','address':'some_address','data_sample':{'sub1':10,'sub2':5,'sub3':1}}"
"{'name':'abc','id':'AB10','address':'some_address','data_sample':{'sub1':20,'sub2':10,'sub3':2}}"
"{'name':'abc','id':'AB10','address':'some_address','data_sample':{'sub1':30,'sub2':15,'sub3': 3}}"
"{'name':'abc','id':'AB10','address':'some_address','data_sample':{'sub1': 40,'sub2':20,'sub3': 4}}"
```

I would like to send this as a parameter in requests.post as following.

```
response=requests.post(url="some_url",data=str_details)
```

If I don't convert to string, gives me an error,
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
If I pass json=str_details, as argument gives me the same error, How to resolve this and get the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build your data use sth like:

```
import copy, json

def make_objects(ref_obj, df):
    objects = []
    for i in range(len(df[df.columns[0]].values)):
        cobj = copy.deepcopy(ref_obj)
        cobj['data_sample'] = {}
        for col in df:
            cobj['data_sample'][col] = int(df[col].values[i]) if df[col].dtype == np.int64 else (float(df[col].values[i]) if df[col].dtype == np.float64 else df[col].values[i])
        objects.append(cobj)
    return objects
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'sub1':[10,20,30,40],'sub2':[5,10,15,20],'sub3':[1,2,3,4]})
objects = make_objects({'name':"abc",'id':"AB10",'address':"some_address"}, df)
# in case you want to json-encode the returned objects
json_output = json.dumps(objects)
```

Comment: Executing the above code results in the following error.TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable

Comment: @Malathi, ok the solution is to typecast the int64 to simple int in order to be json-serializable. Fixed, check it

Comment: @Malathi, else you can simply stringify the int64 (if you dont want to typecast to simple int) and parse the string at other side. So you can also do: `cobj['data_sample'][col] = str(df[col].values[i])`. What suits best your requirements

Comment: @Malathi, you can update your question but better post a new question with the details to the problem you face now.

Comment: `@Nikos M`  The above solution is working, But when  I extended `df` with 1 more column with string values in them. For example `sub4:['sports','music','dance','painting']` I am getting  `'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'`. Howto rectify this error?

Comment: @Malathi, updated to check `dtype` of column. You can adjust as you see fit

Comment: `@Nikos M`The modified suggestion gives the result as follows.`'[{"name": "abc", "id": "AB10", "address": "some_address", "data_sample": {"sub1": 10, "sub2": 5, "sub3": 1}}, {"name": "abc", "id": "AB10", "address": "some_address", "data_sample": {"sub1": 20, "sub2": 10, "sub3": 2}}, {"name": "abc", "id": "AB10", "address": "some_address", "data_sample": {"sub1": 30, "sub2": 15, "sub3": 3}}, {"name": "abc", "id": "AB10", "address": "some_address", "data_sample": {"sub1": 40, "sub2": 20, "sub3": 4}}]'`   and  gives validation error when checking in  `[link](https://jsonlint.com)`

Comment: @Malathi, i checked the example output you provided in jsolint and I dont get any validation error. Are you sure you gave it this specific example? Please post in comment the exact input to jsonlint..

Comment: @Malathi JSON checked as valid in jsonlint `[{"name": "abc", "id": "AB10", "address": "some_address", "data_sample": {"sub1": 10, "sub2": 5, "sub3": 1}}, {"name": "abc", "id": "AB10", "address": "some_address", "data_sample": {"sub1": 20, "sub2": 10, "sub3": 2}}, {"name": "abc", "id": "AB10", "address": "some_address", "data_sample": {"sub1": 30, "sub2": 15, "sub3": 3}}, {"name": "abc", "id": "AB10", "address": "some_address", "data_sample": {"sub1": 40, "sub2": 20, "sub3": 4}}]`

Comment: `@Nikos M` Value your answer. Reproducing the code for my data`payload =make_objects(dd, dataset)`
`pp=json.dumps(payload)` `dd` is dictionary.` pp` is` validJSON` Now
1.   `results_data=requests.post(url=url,data=pp)` gives `status 415, unsupported mediatype `
2     `results_data=requests.post(url=url,data=pp,headers=headers)` gives `status 400`
3.   `results_data=requests.post(url=url,data=payload,headers=headers)`  gives  `too many values to unpack(expected 2) error`  But without square brackets and passing `dictionary element with one row of data` gives me expected result. confused

Comment: `headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}` in the above comment

Comment: @Malathi, the problem is not in `make_objects` which works as expected. Maybe you should not encode to json, but maybe let `requests` encode it instead. But I cannot answer more since this requires to know what the url endpoint is expecting (JSON? POST data? something else?) and use appropriate `requests` parameters (look them up in `requests` documentation)